# Access front camera in android devices using flex-android

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4.5, air-android

There are samples to show how to aceess front camera of android devices using android sdk.Is there any way to do the same using flex hero sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although I'm not sure which version of the AIR SDK that was added to.  Some method somewhere returns an array, and the first item is the back camera and the second item is the front camera.

If I were to guess, I'd say that you use the [Camera class.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html).  [This blog post should give you more information](http://www.riagora.com/2010/07/android-air-and-the-camera/).

Comment: you may use Camera.names method that return an array of camera names.